# Zoom to Selected Feature for point layers in QGIS 2.0

Tags: qgis, plugins

I find the QuickFinder plugin for QGIS 2.0 very useful to quickly search, find, and select data. However, I'm under the impression that checking the "scale" option doesn't seem to do anything. I thought that perhaps it would change the scale of the map and zoom it to a certain level, but my results are the same whether or not this option is checked.

It seems as though Zoom to Selected Feature doesn't change the scale of the map either. I'm wondering if this might be why the scale feature for the Quickfinder doesn't do so. I'm trying to confirm if these are the general effects of these tools or if it is simply my implementation.

After finding this very old ticket: https://trac.osgeo.org/qgis/ticket/154 I still feel confused about the current status of this topic. Does anyone have any ideas of what I may be missing? Thanks in advance.